# Why system call hooking produces different result every time in Linux/Android 2.6.29?

Tags: linux, kernel, android, system-calls

I have implemented system call hooking for `Android 2.6.29` kernel through a `LKM module`. I am tracing down one Android app for system calls. But interestingly, it returns different results every time I get a list of system calls.

I am not able to make bold text in the code section, so I have put ** to show where the difference starts.

For example,

first run:

```
our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30, buf = 230 and count=3 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=230 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_futex ---> uid = 10028 with uadd=������, op=1, val=1, utime=<NULL>, uaddr2=������ and val3=  
 **our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196467192 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196467192 **
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196466496 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3196466496 
 our_sys_dup ---> uid = 10028 with fildes=32 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 32  
 .....................
```

Second run:

```
our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30, buf = 228 and count=3 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=228 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_futex ---> uid = 10028 with uadd=������, op=1, val=1, utime=<NULL>, uaddr2=������ and val3=  
 **our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30, buf = 228 and count=3 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198662648 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198662648 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198661952** 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 30  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=228 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=1181359656 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198661952 
 our_sys_dup ---> uid = 10028 with fildes=32 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 32  
 ....................
```

Third run:

```
our_sys_gettid ---> uid = 10028  
 our_sys_open ---> uid = 10028 with filename= /dev/cpuctl//tasks, flags= 131073, mode=0 
 our_sys_write ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 31, buf = 228 and count=3 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 31  
 our_sys_setpriority ---> uid = 10028 with which= 0, who=228 and niceval=0 
 our_sys_futex ---> uid = 10028 with uadd=������, op=1, val=1, utime=<NULL>, uaddr2=������ and val3=X{�D  
 **our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035960 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035960 
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_clock_gettime ---> uid = 10028 with which_clock=<NULL>, tp =   
 our_sys_munmap ---> uid = 10028 with addr=1183178752 and len=770048 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 32**  
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035264 
 our_sys_ioctl ---> uid = 10028 with fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3198035264 
 our_sys_dup ---> uid = 10028 with fildes=31 
 our_sys_close ---> uid = 10028 with fd= 31  
 ........................
```

Any idea why it's producing different results every time?

Is there any other better tool to trace system calls? I heard of `strace/ptrace`, `auditd` etc but not sure if they are usable for Android or not.

Comment: Is the app you're tracing a Java app or a native one?

Comment: It's just one simple Android app, coded in Java.

Comment: Then you can't really expect anything deterministic. You'll see VM background activity (GC in particular but that's not the only thing). Try tracing any Java app on a regular Linux box with strace, it is really chatty.

Comment: I used strace binaries on Android emulator but it was giving me list of some system calls (msgget() and msgrecv() ) which are not even implemented by Android as pointed out by Chris at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110856/how-to-find-system-call-implementations-in-linux-android-2-6-29

Answer (score 1):

I advice you run and trace your app on a real device rather than on an emulator. Emulator lacks certain functionality possessed by real device and so trying to do certain task with emulator will really produce unstable results.